# Managing static pages from admin interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, admin

I have few static pages(`Contacts`, `About us`, etc) in my rails app. Admin interface realized by separating routes(`namespace :admin do ...`). How I can manage static(!) content in static pages only from admin interface? Thanks

Comment: how is your static (!) content provided?
Is it html / haml files in your public folder?

Comment: In fact this page has not yet exist. I just think it would be better to implement from. For example `Contact` page will be a form of feedback. Maybee. On the other hand I think `About` will be semi-static, becouse there may be a list of users or something else(not static). If you can, please recommend me how it could have been done better?

Comment: this is not a question of recommendation but of requirements.  
Could you please provide information of what you want an administrator to be able to change and what will stay static - maybe there are solutions that can be provideable.

What about my answer - does this help you?

Comment: A partly. I found solution in Ryan's railscasts #117. But thank you too.

Comment: ok, so you moved the content to the database

Comment: Yes. I decide that content is not so big and I can store it in db. For example `title`, `content`, `permalink`(and fields for meta tags ) and it is enough. But you gave me the idea to use `File` class in my other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a authorization solution like Ryan Bates' [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or elabs' [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).
There you can easily define the ability for only admin-users regarding restful actions in the `:admin` namespace.

Then you can use Ruby's `File` class (docs for [1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html) or [2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html)) to manipulate the files (only when the users are admins) as you want to.

But be aware of caching mechanisms:
If you are caching these files (e.g. on your server nginx, unicorn or a caching-solution e.g. varnish, squid), they must be purged out of the cache so you can view the changes.